# Order of Complexity of customized tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, generic-programming

Please tell me the complexity of below tree.
Please explanation the procedure of calculating it also.

**The tree structure:**

[image: Below is the tree structure]

root->left->right and root->right->left are pointing to same node.

Algorithm:  If we traverse the tree with normal inorder traversal, then we will visit some nodes more than 1 time.

like

node4(2 times) 0->1->4 and 0->2->4

node7(3 times) 0->1->3->7, 0->1->4->7, 0->2->4->7

What will be the order of complexity of above algo?

Comment: Well, the storage complexity is O(N)… but if you want to know the complexity of an algorithm on this data structure, you'll have to describe the algorithm.

Comment: This is basically useless in practice, as a search tree. If you have any particular use in mind, you have to specify that to have any hope of getting an answer.

Comment: @Rob: algorithm updated in question

Comment: @yzt: question was asked in an interview. So uses of this data structure doesn't matter, want to know the complexity only.

Answer (score 2):

In your diagrammed structure (which is a directed acyclic graph or “DAG”, not a tree), a traversal will visit two children for every node except the leaf nodes. Therefore it will visit a total of 2<sup>h</sup>-1 nodes (counting duplicates), where h is the height of the DAG. (The height is 5 in your diagram.)

Assuming the DAG is fully populated, then n (the number of nodes in the DAG) must be h(h+1)/2. (This is Gauss's formula for summing the integers from 1 through h.)

[Solving n = h(h+1)/2 for h gives us h = (sqrt(8n + 1) - 1)/2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n+%3D+h%28h%2B1%29%2F2+for+h), so the total number of nodes visited, in terms of n, is 2<sup>(sqrt(8n + 1) - 1)/2</sup> - 1.

#### UPDATE

The traversal function would look like this:

```
def traverse(node):
    if node.left is not None:
        traverse(node.left)
    print(node.data)
    if node.right is not None:
        traverse(node.right)
```

Notice that `traverse` doesn't look at a node's parent, only its children. From `traverse`'s point of view, it is irrelevant that some nodes are shared (and therefore have two parents). It cannot tell the difference between your DAG and a normal binary tree.

Every one of your DAG's interior nodes has exactly two children. So, from `traverse`'s point of view, your DAG is identical to a fully-populated binary tree of height h. A fully-populated binary tree of height h has 2<sup>h</sup>-1 nodes.

Comment: As this is not normal binary tree, How did you say that nodes are getting accessed pow(2,h)-1 times.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we check level wise that how many times a level are getting traverse, then we will reach to below output

level 1 - 1times

level 2 - 2times

level 3 - 4times

level 4 - 8times

level 5 - 14times

upto

level h

total traversal is : 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 14 + ... upto h level

split series into 2 series:

(1+0) + (2+0) + (3+1) + (4+4) + (5+9) + ... h+sqOf(h-2)

means

1+2+3+4+ ... +h

+

sqOf(1) + sqOf(2) + sqOf(3) + ... +sqOf(h-2)

=>h(h+1)/2 + (h-2)(h-1)(2h-3)/6

so order of complexity become cubeOf(h) where h is (sqrt(8n + 1) - 1)/2 (as rob mayoff explained)